# How do I check if the Java JDK is installed on Mac?

Tags: macos, java

How do you check if Java SDK is installed on a Mac?

Is there a command line for this?

Comment: *" that software aren't running"*  What is the error output?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

`javac -version` in a terminal will do

Comment: I got "javac 1.6.0_37" is it equivalent of jdk 6 or 7?

Comment: However, if Java isn't installed, a dialog box will appear telling you that Java needs to be installed, so this isn't a good option for scripts.

Comment: If you get "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.", got to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html and download java jdk!

Comment: this doesn't show any sdk path; only shows java runtime version for me on macOS 12.1, is it because I didn't install the sdk?

Comment: To show the path where the java jdk installed, use command "which javac". Also regarding the version naming, Java 8 is Java 1.8, where 8 is the version number, and 1.8 is the version string

Answer (score 110):

You can leverage the `java_home` helper binary on `OS X` for what you're looking for.

To list all versions of installed JDK:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.0_51, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_79, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
```

To request the JAVA_HOME path of a specific JDK version, you can do:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You could take advantage of the above commands in your script like this:

```
REQUESTED_JAVA_VERSION="1.7"
if POSSIBLE_JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $REQUESTED_JAVA_VERSION 2>/dev/null)"; then
    # Do this if you want to export JAVA_HOME
    export JAVA_HOME="$POSSIBLE_JAVA_HOME"
    echo "Java SDK is installed"
else
    echo "Did not find any installed JDK for version $REQUESTED_JAVA_VERSION"
fi
```

You might be able to do if-else and check for multiple different versions of java as well.

If you prefer XML output, java_home also has a -X option to output in XML.

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home --help
Usage: java_home [options...]
    Returns the path to a Java home directory from the current user's settings.

Options:
    [-v/--version   <version>]       Filter Java versions in the "JVMVersion" form 1.X(+ or *).
    [-a/--arch      <architecture>]  Filter JVMs matching architecture (i386, x86_64, etc).
    [-d/--datamodel <datamodel>]     Filter JVMs capable of -d32 or -d64
    [-t/--task      <task>]          Use the JVM list for a specific task (Applets, WebStart, BundledApp, JNI, or CommandLine)
    [-F/--failfast]                  Fail when filters return no JVMs, do not continue with default.
    [   --exec      <command> ...]   Execute the $JAVA_HOME/bin/<command> with the remaining arguments.
    [-R/--request]                   Request installation of a Java Runtime if not installed.
    [-X/--xml]                       Print full JVM list and additional data as XML plist.
    [-V/--verbose]                   Print full JVM list with architectures.
    [-h/--help]                      This usage information.
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to find the path of my java versions

Answer (score 17):

Type in  a terminal:

```
which javac
```

It should show you something like

```
/usr/bin/javac
```

Comment: -1 for the answer: the presence of java command in the path doesn't testify that the JDK is installed (but the JRE)

Comment: I agree. I could run "which java" or "which javac", but I got an error message when running "java --version" because JDK is not installed.

Comment: -1 This is completely wrong. All Macs come with a `javac` shim by default. It bears no relation to whether or not Java is installed.

Comment: 16 people say, this answer is helpful. Although it is incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

Below command worked out pretty good:

```
javac -version
```

I also manually verified by navigating to the Java Folder on my Mac

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk
```

Answer (score 5):

`/usr/bin/java_home` tool returns 1 if java not installed.

So you can check if java is installed by the next way:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home &> /dev/null && echo "installed" || echo  "not installed"
```

Comment: annnnnnd it returns -127 if `/usr/libexec/java_home` doesn't even exist... so this actually works both ways ;-)

Answer (score 3):

- Open terminal.
- run command to see:

  javac -version
- Also you can verify manually by going to the specific location and then check. To do this run below command in the mac terminal

  cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Then run `ls` command in the terminal again. Now you can see the jdk version & package if exists in your computer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mac OS Big Sur, then you probably have a messed up java installation.
I found info on how to fix the issue with this article:
https://knasmueller.net/how-to-install-java-openjdk-15-on-macos-big-sur

1. Download the .tar.gz file of the JDK on https://jdk.java.net/15/
2. Navigate to the download folder, and run these commands (move the .tar.gz file, extract it and remove it after extraction):

```
sudo mv openjdk-15.0.2_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
sudo tar -xzf openjdk-15.0.2_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz
sudo rm openjdk-15.0.2_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

Note: it might be 15.0.3 or higher, depending on the date of your download.

3. run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v15` and copy the output
4. add this line to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` file, depending on which shell you are using. You will probably have only one of these files existing in your home directory (`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`).

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

5. save the changes and make them effective right away by running:
   `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.zshrc`
6. check that java is working - run `java -v`

Answer (score 2):

On MAC find your JDK path by executing the command.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Answer (score 1):

Just type `javac`. If it is installed you get usage information, otherwise it would just ask if you would like to install Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only check Java is already installed or not

just type- **java** on the terminal

and if you want to know about the version as well then

type- **java -version** on the terminal

Result will be look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you correctly define the project's JDK and restart IntelliJ (full restart).