# Mac OS X and multiple Java versions

Tags: java, macos, multiple-versions, homebrew-cask, jenv

How can I install an additional java on MacOS?  I installed jdk8 and that works fine. But now I need a jdk7 installation for development purposes. When trying to install the old version via DMG file, i get a warning, that there is already a newer version of java installed and the installer quits.

```
    /usr/libexec/java_home -verbose
    Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
        1.8.0_20, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home

       /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
```

How to install jdk7 in addition to this one?

Comment: Warning: the Homebrew Java installation commands recommended by the top answers don't work anymore.  See my answer for the latest commands or [this amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524114/1125159) that has all the latest commands with detailed explanations on the different approaches.

Comment: https://medium.com/@kirebyte/using-homebrew-to-install-java-jdk11-on-macos-2021-4a90aa276f1c 
this solution work for me.

Answer (score 636, accepted):

The cleanest way to manage multiple java versions on Mac is to use [`Homebrew`](http://brew.sh).

And within `Homebrew`, use:

- `homebrew-cask` to install the versions of java
- `jenv` to manage the installed versions of java

---

As seen on http://hanxue-it.blogspot.ch/2014/05/installing-java-8-managing-multiple.html , these are the steps to follow.

1. install homebrew
2. install homebrew jenv
3. install homebrew-cask
4. install a specific java version using cask (see "homebrew-cask versions" paragraph below)
5. add this version for jenv to manage it
6. check the version is correctly managed by jenv
7. repeat steps 4 to 6 for each version of java you need

---

#### homebrew-cask versions

Add the [`homebrew/cask-versions`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions) tap to homebrew using:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
```

Then you can look at all the versions available:

```
brew search java
```

Then you can install the version(s) you like:

```
brew install --cask java7
brew install --cask java6
```

And add them to be managed by jenv as usual.

```
jenv add <javaVersionPathHere>
```

I think this is the cleanest & simplest way to go about it.

---

Another important thing to note, as mentioned in [Mac OS X 10.6.7 Java Path Current JDK confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141180/mac-os-x-10-6-7-java-path-current-jdk-confusing/24792251#24792251) :

> For different types of JDKs or installations, you will have different
> paths
>
> You can check the paths of the versions installed using `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, see [How do I check if the Java JDK is installed on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292698/how-do-i-check-if-the-java-jdk-is-installed-on-mac)
>
> On Mac OS X Mavericks, I found as following:
>
> 1. Built-in JRE default: `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`
> 2. JDKs downloaded from Apple: `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/`
> 3. JDKs downloaded from Oracle: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home`

---

#### Resources

- [Removing Java 8 JDK from Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-jdk-from-mac)
- http://hanxue-it.blogspot.ch/2014/05/installing-java-8-managing-multiple.html
- http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/index.html
- http://brew.sh
- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tree/master/share/doc/homebrew#readme
- http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Homebrew/README.html
- "brew tap” explained https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/brew-tap.md
- “brew versions” explained [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) and also https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions
- https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask
- “cask versions”, similar to “brew versions”, see https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-versions and also https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/9447
- http://www.jenv.be
- https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv

Comment: It would be good to mention that homebrew-cask can be installed with command `brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask` instead of `brew install cask` which is an Emacs plugin.

Comment: Do we have to delete the current installed version of Java (1.8), and reinstalling it with brew to be able to brew-manage both?

Comment: Don't think you have to. As mentioned in the last step of the installation process, use `jenv add <javaVersionPathHere>` to let jenv know where it can find a given java version.

Comment: I just wanted to mention, since it wasn't working for me. `brew cask install java7` downloads the package file but doesn't install it. You still need manually install it. Then you should be able to add the path to `jenv`

Also, `brew cask search java` doesn't return java8 for some reason.

Comment: @squid267 the cleanest way is to avoid homebrew. Try Vegard solution, I added a comment that should help you (but before download and install by yourself the jdk or jre you want http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: @squid267 did you open a ticket on [Github on `Homebrew Cask`'s repo](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask)? I doubt this is a normal behavior.

Comment: @Nico Why would you avoid a generic solution that was [contributed by 100 people since April 2012](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/graphs/contributors) & tested by 10s of thousands? it has 2,315 Closed vs 64 Opened issues... just look at the repo, numbers speak for themselves, it's a pretty damn good tool

Comment: @AdrienBe I tried homeBrew two years ago and I encountered several problems when I wanted to change for example mysql versions, then I decided to do things by my own. But you must be right, maybe today this tool is better. I think it's a choice, for people confortable with mac os command lines and system administration maybe avoid homebrew is better in order to keep a better view of what is installed.

Comment: @Nico yeah, in the end one should just try out & choose whatever (s)he feels comfortable with. Some tools are just irrelevant if you have the relevant skills already, sys admin stuff in this case. Although one could actually like this as it avoids you having to do repetitive work...

Comment: I ran into a few problems while implementing this solution, one of which was with `jenv` returning the `No such file or directory.` error. This wiki helped solve it for me.
https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv/wiki/Trouble-Shooting

Comment: I would add that all java installs would be in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` and when adding them with `jenv add` you add path looking like this `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/[specific-version]/Contents/Home/`. Cheers!

Comment: @SammyKumar I think java8 isn't listed because 8 is what you get by default when you just use `brew cask install java`

Comment: As of Jun 23 2017, I run `brew cask search java7` but got No Cask found for "java7".

Comment: @MingliangLIU yeah me too... it really sucks. I found issues about this on Github were they mentioned some work arounds but I could not get it to work. So I ended up having to do it "the manual way" via apple and oracle's "Java versions download and install" web pages. Then using `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to double check the paths where these were installed.

Comment: @AdrienBe Thanks for sharing this. As this is confirmed, I'll also install manually. Hadoop 2 is still using Java 7, unfortunately...

Comment: Step 2.5. `$ eval "$(jenv init -)"` as per linked page.

Comment: is there a way to install a specific version with Java8. For eg 1.8.0_151-b12 or older within Java 8? thanks

Comment: I really want this to work.. but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to use openjdk..

Comment: @AdrienBe you should update your answer with the current ways to install java, which is cask "brew cask install java8" "brew cask install java-beta" "brew cask install java" "brew cask install java7" .. there is no tap anymore. changed a lot. Thanks for the brief answer

Comment: It took awhile for me to figure out the path to Java Home for the instruction, jenv add <javaVersionPathHere> . If you put the command, /usr/libexec/java_home -V just below it would be a good enhancement.

Comment: For [Homebrew 2.6.0+](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/#:~:text=All%20brew%20cask%20commands%20have,Homebrew.), replaces `cask install` with `install --cask`.

Comment: `$ brew install --cask java8`
now gives
`Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`
`brew search java` actually lists `java6` but neither `java7` nor `java8`!

Comment: After trying a couple of other commands this one worked; be prepared to have a *github* login and your admin account password ready:
`brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: Here's the stuff about searching through the different places `brew` might store your Java8, spelled out in more detail: https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-install-uninstall-multiple-java-versions-in-mac-os-by-home-brew-or-manually/

Comment: is this still valid with Big Sur OS ?

Comment: @Adelin yes and also for Monterey :)

Comment: when you cant add the desired and downloaded version, please [reopen](https://github.com/jenv/jenv/issues/167#issuecomment-292477397) the terminal.

Answer (score 427):

Uninstall jdk8, install jdk7, then reinstall jdk8.

My approach to switching between them (in .profile) :

```
export JAVA_7_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.7)
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_9_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v9)
export JAVA_20_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v20)

alias java7='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_7_HOME'
alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java9='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_9_HOME'
alias java20='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_20_HOME'

#default java8
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME
```

Then you can simply type `java7` or `java8` in a terminal to switch versions.

(edit: updated to add Dylans improvement for Java 9)

Comment: So far this is the best option for me. easily can switch to any version with just a simple command "java8" or "java7". Thanks for the help

Comment: Great ! :) And for other like me you can use : ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines to see which versions are available. Then you can switch on different 1.8.x versions. And also you have to add export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: Thanks for this one. I just wanted to mention that I've managed to do this by installing jdk7 after jdk8 (there is no need to uninstall jdk8).

Comment: Dunno why I wasted my time with jenv, as this just works, and does not clutter your shell startup by 0.5s with jenv init.

Comment: If you are trying to get java 9 working in this fashion, the version argument to java_home for java 9 should simply be `9` e.g. `export JAVA_9_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v9)`

Comment: Thanks for this!  Had Java8 installed with homebrew already, installed 9 as well, did this (sans jdk7) and it seems to be working.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, much simpler than installing extraneous software, especially if you're using a corporate managed Mac where there are restrictions on software that can be installed.

Comment: Along similar lines, you can also use a tool like direnv to specify Java versions per project so you don't need to remember to switch yourself. All it does it automatically set JAVA_HOME. I've outlined this approach here: https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/4c66a0f09f545320e52bb4a559777a88

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, the alias commands shouldn't have backticks (`) around them but instead single quotes ('). Otherwise the alias just gets set to the output of the export command (blank) rather than the export command itself

Comment: Yes, that was a late edit from someone else, I'll revert. Thanks @willrochathomas.

Comment: This is the answer guys. `/usr/libexec/java_home` is awesome. Read about it a bit more. It's all you need.

Comment: If you are on Big Sur, make sure to follow the advice outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917842/5114189) answer. Looks like Big Sur broke the way `usr/libexec/java_home` worked in previous versions, so setting `JAVA_HOME` in advance won't work.

Comment: @msilb apparently this was caused by a bug that has later been fixed.

Comment: If you use zsh, then add aforementioned exports on ~/.zprofile

Comment: In the alias commands, I have to re-export the PATH, like:
alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME;export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"'

So that the right version's bin is in the front of the PATH.

Comment: this is really the best solution. Without the need to play with the brew cask. I love this so much.

Answer (score 174):

### For macOS Sierra 420

This guide was cobbled together from various sources (replies above as well as other posts), and works perfect.

#### 0. If you haven't already, install homebrew.

See https://brew.sh/

#### 1. Install jenv

```
brew install jenv
```

#### 2. Add jenv to the bash profile

```
if which jenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(jenv init -)"; fi
```

#### 3. Add jenv to your path

```
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/shims:$PATH"
```

#### 4. Tap "homebrew/cask-versions"

FYI: "Tap" extends brew's list of available repos it can install, above and beyond brew's default list of available repos.

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
```

#### 5. Install the latest version of java

```
brew install java --cask
```

#### 6. Install java 6 (or 7 or 8 whatever you need)

```
brew install java6 --cask
#brew install java7 --cask
#brew install java8 --cask
```

? Maybe close and restart Terminal so it sees any new ENV vars that got setup.

#### 7. Review Installations

Most Java version get installed here: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` lets take a look.

```
ls -la /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

NOTE: Sometimes java ends up here: `/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin/java`, so you can peek into the "opt" dir and look for "openjdk" in the list with:

```
ls -la /usr/local/opt/
```

#### 8. Add each path to jenv one-at-a-time.

We need to add "/Contents/Home" to the version folder.
WARNING: Use the actual paths on your machine... these are just ***EXAMPLE***'s

```
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0___EXAMPLE___/Contents/Home
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk___EXAMPLE___/Contents/Home
```

TIP: If you think you already have java, but not sure where it is, try using "which" -- if you have java installed, "which" should print out the path to java:

```
which java
```

#### 9. Check if jenv registered OK

```
jenv versions
```

#### 10. Set java version to use (globably)

Where XX matches one of the items in the versions list above.

```
jenv global XX
```

#### Check java version

```
java -version
```

NOTE: If not seeing version, enable plugin export (see comments below from cakraww):

```
jenv enable-plugin export
```

#### Check jenv versions

Should also indicate the current version being used with an asterisk.

```
jenv versions
```

#### DONE

---

### Quick future reference

To change java versions

... See the list of available java versions

```
jenv versions
```

... then, where XX matches an item in the list above

```
jenv global XX
```

... also check which java the system recognizes (see TIP in #8 above)

```
which java
```

Comment: Additionally, restart your terminal after `brew cask install java*`

Comment: Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

Comment: java8/9/10 arent available anymore as casks. Try this instead: 
" brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8 "

Comment: By default `jenv` does not set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. You need to enable the plugin by `jenv enable-plugin export`.

Comment: `brew tap caskroom/versions` should be `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions`

Comment: Great work!  Even better than steps 7, 8 use - `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and then `jenv add <what that returns>` or you could script it - `for ver in $(/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -v Matching | awk '{print $1}'); do echo X: $(jenv add $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v$ver)); done`

Comment: The `2>&1 >/dev/null` is because the versions from java_home are printed to `STDERR` and the actual version being used is printed to `STDOUT`.

Comment: Great instructions; I'm on osx 10.15.3; step 3 above duplicates step 2; also, /Library/Java/Extensions was working for Java SE 8, but doesn't work for adoptopenjdk-9, so I use "java -cp 'path_to_jars'" instead, which is awkward.

Comment: When running `jenv add <>`, if you get an error like this :  `ln: ~/.jenv/versions/openjdk64-11.0.8: No such file or directory`, then it means .jenv/versions folder is missing; creating one (`mkdir ~/.jenv/versions`), then re-running `jenv add <>` should solve the problem

Comment: Many of these tips/instructions are applicable to other mac versions (including M1s)

Answer (score 87):

[SDKMAN!](http://sdkman.io/) is a great tool for using multiple versions of Java, Gradle, Groovy, Kotlin, and other JVM tools on Mac OS. Installation and usage doc are easily found on the main site.

(I have no affiliation, just a happy user).

As an example usage, if I type the following in a Terminal window, there is a list of available Java SDK versions (edited for brevity):

```
$ sdk list java
Available Java Versions
   + 17.0.9-oracle                                                                        
 > + 11.0.21-zulu                                                                         
     21.0.1-tem
```

Here `+` denotes that the version is installed. `>` denotes which version is currently in use. To install a version:

```
$ sdk install java 21.0.1-tem
```

To use a version in this Terminal window:

```
$ sdk use java 21.0.1-tem
```

Comment: sdkman supports versions starting with java 1.7. If you're willing to use java 1.6 this solution may not be suitable for you.

Comment: sdkman is great, but they dont support specific releases within a version. For example Datastax Dev Center only works with 1.8.0_151 but I can't specify that with sdkman. Hopefully they add more versions.

Comment: If you have a local version, I think you can install it into SDKMan - https://sdkman.io/usage#localversion (but I haven't tried it)

Comment: This was the perfect solution for me. thank you. I wasn't happy with the way jenv worked (or lack of working in my case) but found this to be sdkman to get the job done for me allowing me to run LSP-Metal in sublime 3 and code scala.

Answer (score 21):

First, you need to make certain you have multiple JAVA versions installed.
Open a new Terminal window and input:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Your output should look like:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
11.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_201, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Note that there are two JDKs available. If you don’t notice the Java version you need to switch to, download and install the appropriate one from here https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/
(JDK 8 is represented as 1.8) .
Once you have installed the appropriate JDK, repeat this step.

2. Take note of the JDK version you want to switch to. For example, “11.0” and “1.8” are the JDK versions available in the example above.
3. Switch to the desired version. For example, if you wish to switch to JDK 8, input the following line:

   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

For 11.0, switch “1.8” with “11.0”
4. Check your JDK version by inputting into Terminal:

```
java -version
```

If you have followed all the steps correctly, the JDK version should correlate with the one you specified in the last step.
5. (Optional) To make this the default JDK version, input the following in Terminal:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, add your Terminal input from step 3 to this file:

## SWITCH TO JAVA VERSION 8

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Save and close the file.

Comment: Did you mean to include a link with "download and install the appropriate one from here"?

Comment: No the link is to help download jdk from oracle site

Answer (score 9):

In the same spirit than @Vegard (lightweight):

- Install the wanted JDKs with Homebrew
- Put this `jdk` bash function and a default in your `.profile`

  ```
  jdk() {
      version=$1
      export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v"$version");
      java -version
   }

  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11); # Your default version
  ```
- and then, to switch your jdk, you can do

  ```
   jdk 9
   jdk 11
   jdk 13
  ```

Based on https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk.

Answer (score 7):

As found on this [website](http://javahabit.com/2015/03/30/install-or-manage-multiple-versions-of-java-on-os-x/)
So Let’s begin by installing jEnv

1. Run this in the terminal

   ```
   brew install https://raw.github.com/gcuisinier/jenv/homebrew/jenv.rb
   ```
2. Add jEnv to the bash profile

   ```
   if which jenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(jenv init -)"; fi
   ```
3. When you first install jEnv will not have any JDK associated with it.

   For example, I just installed JDK 8 but jEnv does not know about it. To check Java versions on jEnv

   At the moment it only found Java version(jre) on the system. The `*` shows the version currently selected. Unlike rvm and rbenv, jEnv cannot install JDK for you. You need to install JDK manually from Oracle website.
4. Install JDK 6 from Apple website. This will install Java in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. The reason we are installing Java 6 from Apple website is that SUN did not come up with JDK 6 for MAC, so Apple created/modified its own deployment version.
5. Similarly install JDK7 and JDK8.
6. Add JDKs to jEnv.

   JDK 6:

   JDK 7:
   [image: http://javahabi@javahabit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/img_5518ab9bc47d4.png]

   JDK 8:
   [image: http://javahabi@javahabit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/img_5518abb2c1217.png]
7. Check the java versions installed using jenv

   [image: http://javahabi@javahabit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/img_5518abceb0deb.png]
8. So now we have 3 versions of Java on our system. To set a default version use the command

   ```
   jenv local <jenv version>
   ```

   Ex – I wanted Jdk 1.6 to start IntelliJ

   ```
   jenv local oracle64-1.6.0.65
   ```
9. check the java version

   java -version
   [image: http://javahabi@javahabit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/img_5518abe376dd0.png]

That’s it. We now have multiple versions of java and we can switch between them easily. jEnv also has some other features, such as wrappers for Gradle, Ant, Maven, etc, and the ability to set JVM options globally or locally. Check out the documentation for more information.

Comment: Do not put images of your commands, it makes difficult to copy/paste them. To highlight commands, use the backticks "`" for a single word or a short command, or indent your command with 4 spaces on its own line (or multiples of 4 in lists).

Comment: Thanks Seki. I was struggling to post images and spent a long time trying to format but could not get it right. Thanks for sharing the backticks info.

Comment: I think you may have used the same image four times.

Answer (score 7):

Manage multiple java version in MAC using jenv

1. Install homebrew using following command

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
   ```
2. install jenv and activate jenv

   ```
   brew install jenv

   echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
3. tap cask-versions

   ```
   brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
   ```
4. search available java version that can be installed

   ```
   brew search java
   ```
5. E.g. to install java6 use following command

   ```
   brew install cask java6
   ```
6. Add multiple versions of java in jenv

   ```
   jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home

   jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
   ```

Note:- if you get error like `ln: /Users/<username>/.jenv/versions/oracle64-1.8.0.231: No such file or directory`, then run following:-

```
   mkdir -p /Users/<username>/.jenv/versions/oracle64-1.8.0.231
```

7. Rehash jenv after adding jdk’s

   ```
   jenv rehash
   ```
8. List known versions of java to jenv

   ```
   jenv versions
   ```
9. Set default version

   ```
   jenv global oracle64-1.8.0.231
   ```
10. Change java version for a project

    ```
    jenv local oracle64-1.6.0.65
    ```
11. set JAVA_HOME with the same version as jenv

    ```
    jenv exec bash

    echo $JAVA_HOME
    ```

Answer (score 6):

I find this Java version manager called [Jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba) recently and the usage is very similar to version managers of other languages like rvm(ruby), nvm(node), pyenv(python), etc. Also it's cross platform so definitely it can be used on Mac.

After installation, it will create a dir in ~/.jabba to put all the Java versions you install. It "Supports installation of Oracle JDK (default) / Server JRE, Zulu OpenJDK (since 0.3.0), IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition (since 0.6.0) and from custom URLs.".

Basic usage is listed on their Github. A quick summary to start:

```
curl -sL https://github.com/shyiko/jabba/raw/master/install.sh | bash && . ~/.jabba/jabba.sh

# install Oracle JDK
jabba install 1.8 # "jabba use 1.8" will be called automatically  
jabba install 1.7 # "jabba use 1.7" will be called automatically 

# list all installed JDK's
jabba ls

# switch to a different version of JDK
jabba use 1.8
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using Mac OS X 10.9.5. This is how I manage multiple JDK/JRE on my machine when I need one version to run application A and use another version for application B.

I created the following script after getting some help online.

```
#!bin/sh
function setjdk() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
   removeFromPath '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/'
   if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then
    removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME
   fi
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/$1/Contents/Home
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
 }
 function removeFromPath() {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
 }
#setjdk jdk1.8.0_60.jdk
setjdk jdk1.7.0_15.jdk
```

I put the above script in .profile file. Just open terminal, type vi .profile, append the script with the above snippet and save it. Once your out type `source .profile`, this will run your profile script without you having to restart the terminal. Now type `java -version` it should show 1.7 as your current version. If you intend to change it to 1.8 then comment the line `setjdk jdk1.7.0_15.jdk` and uncomment the line `setjdk jdk1.8.0_60.jdk`. Save the script and run it again with source command. I use this mechanism to manage multiple versions of JDK/JRE when I have to compile 2 different Maven projects which need different java versions.

Answer (score 5):

Jenv on Mac Sierra:

if not working after install, do this bug fix to add java executable to path

```
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/shims:$PATH"
```

even though `eval "$(jenv init -)"` could do this job. The reason is /bin folder is not there anymore as describe in it's homepage, but shim folder is used as /bin instead.

- Make sure ~/.jenv is there
- `which java` may print /Library/...
- jenv global 1.8
- jenv shell 1.8

Eventually, `which java` gives you:

> /Users/xxxx/.jenv/shims/java

Answer (score 5):

I answer lately and I really recommand you to use [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) instead of Homebrew.

With SDKMAN you can install easily different version of JAVA in your mac and switch from on version to another.

[image: Java in your mac]

You can also use SDKMAN for ANT, GRADLE, KOTLIN, MAVEN, SCALA, etc...

To install a version in your mac you can run the command sdk install java 15.0.0.j9-adpt
[image: cmd]

Comment: what is the difference between `sdkman` and `jenv`?

Comment: @Exploring jenv is also a good option, sdkman include also kotlin, gradle, maven, ant, asciidotorJ and many other tools needed for a developer

Answer (score 5):

I know that this question already have a lot of answers, but I want to share my solution only using Temurin and bash.

> [AdoptOpenJdk](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk) is deprecated and that is why I'm using [Temurin](https://adoptium.net/).

---

**1.** Download Temurin using the mirrors or a package manager

`$ brew install --cask temurin`

And for other versions (like Java 8):

`$ brew tap homebrew/cask-versions`

`$ brew install --cask temurin8`

---

**2.** Add a bash script into your bash profile

Open your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (depending on what you're using it)

And add this code:

```sh
set-jdk() {
    jdkversion=$1
    export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-"$jdkversion".jdk/Contents/Home;
    export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin;
    java -version
}
```

---

**3.** Restart your terminal and change your Java version

`$ set-jdk N` N being the Java version that you want and it's already installed

e.g.
`$ set-jdk 8` To change to Java 8 / 1.8

---

Few considerations:

- It will only keep the Java version on the terminal session that you used the `set-jdk` command
- It won't set the Java version as global
- When you want to add the JAVA_HOME into another script/application, you can set `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-<version>.jdk/Contents/Home` (change the  for the desired Java version. Like this [JD-GUI example](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/issues/332#issuecomment-753706520))

---

**Enjoy**

Comment: This is good! Do you really need: export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin; ?

Answer (score 5):

As of `2023`, `brew install --cask zulu8` didn't work for me on `Apple` chip. `brew install openjdk@8` also didn't not. The only one solution worked for me was `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8` and then of course `vim ~/.zshrc` and inside:

```bash
export JAVAC_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
alias javac8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVAC_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'
alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
```

switch from terminal using `javac8` to a freshly installed (different) version. Note: you can have different `Java` versions than me, so it's just an example.

Edit: for some reason it takes some time once it's activate. It seems to me a restart of a laptop is needed.

Comment: That was super helpful thanks. Just FYI, if you run `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` then it will update your available casks and you can then install both Zulu versions. It works for me on Mac M1. `brew install --cask zulu8` and `brew install --cask zulu11`

Comment: side question: what are the differences between `openjdk`, `adoptopenjdk8`, `zulu`, etc? Why one will be preferred over the others?

Comment: @VimNing good one, but tbh, I don't know :-( it's just what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**New commands for installing Java via Homebrew:**

- `brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`
- `brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk11`

See the [homebrew-openjdk](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk) repo for the latest commands.

**Installing Java**

You can install Java via Homebrew, Jabba, SDKMAN or manually.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524114/1125159) for details on all the commands.

**Switching Java versions***

You can switch Java versions with [jenv](https://mungingdata.com/java/jenv-multiple-versions-java/) Jabba, SDKMAN or manually.  See details on all the switching commands [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524112/how-do-i-install-java-on-mac-osx-allowing-version-switching/52524114#52524114).

**Best solutions**

- Jabba is designed to work on multiple platforms, so it's a good option if you want a solution that'll also work on Windows
- Using Homebrew to download Java versions and jenv to switch versions provides a nice workflow.  jenv makes it easy to work with Java versions stored in any directory on your machine, so it's a good alternative if you're interested in storing Java in non-default directories.
- Using SDKMAN to download Javas and switch versions is another great alternative
- Manually switching should be avoided because it's an unnecessary headache.

**Function to manually switch Java versions**

Here's the Bash / ZSH function for manually switching Java versions (by [OpenJDK](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk)):

```
jdk() {
        version=$1
        export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v"$version");
        java -version
 }
```

There are great tools for switching Java versions, so I highly recommend against doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

To find the available Java versions:

```
brew search java
```

To install the latest stable version (19 as of today):

```
brew info java
brew install java
```

For the system Java wrappers (eg: IDEs) to find the latest JDK, symlink it with:

```
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

To install a specific version (11):

```
brew install java11
```

For the system, Java wrappers to find JDK 11:

```
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
```

You can have one of the OpenJDK versions in your PATH. Add one of the following lines to your ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH
```

Then,

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error on my mac m1 air just by adding the path of new jdk version in ~/.zshrc file.

```
export PATH="SPATH:/Users/ayushpattnaik/Documents/Deyeloper/flutter/bin"
export JAVA_HOME=nibrary/Jaya/JayaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

```bash
[ayushpattnaik@Ayushs—MacBook—Air ~ % java —version
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.18+0) 
OpenJDK 64—Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.18+0, mixed mode)
```

I have multiple jdks in my `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` path. So I can choose any version I wish to set as my default java path.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more DRY version for bash (Based on Vegard's answer)

Replace 1.7 and 1.8 with whatever versions you are interested with
and you'll get an alias called 'javaX'; where 'X' is the java version (7 / 8 in the snippet below) that will allow you to easily switch versions

```
for version in 1.7 1.8; do
    v="${version: -1}"
    h=JAVA_"$v"_HOME

    export "$h"=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $version)

    alias "java$v"="export JAVA_HOME=\$$h"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To install more recent versions of OpenJDK, I use this. Example for OpenJDK 14:

```sh
brew info adoptopenjdk
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk14
```

See https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk for current info.

Answer (score 0):

I followed steps in below link - https://medium.com/@euedofia/fix-default-java-version-on-maven-on-mac-os-x-156cf5930078 and it worked for me.

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.4/bin/
nano mvn
--Update JAVA_HOME -> "${JAVA_HOME:-$(/usr/libexec/java_home)}"
mvn -version
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tutorial
https://medium.com/@chamikakasun/how-to-manage-multiple-java-version-in-macos-e5421345f6d0
by using jEnv installed by brew

or you can check out homebrew-openjdk
https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk managing version using brew Tap

Answer (score 0):

When you want to maintain multiple JDK version (already installed) in Mac M1 then to switch easily between them add following lines in your ~/.zshrc file

```
alias jdk11="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`; java -version"
alias jdk8="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`; java -version"
```

Now, these can be easily switched like following

```
% ~
: jdk8
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.72.0.17-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.72.0.17-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)
% ~
: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.72.0.17-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.72.0.17-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)
% ~
:
% ~
: jdk11
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.15.9.1 (build 11.0.15+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.15.9.1 (build 11.0.15+9-LTS, mixed mode)
% ~
: java -version
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
```

Answer (score 0):

For mac os user

- First list the existing all java with this command

  ~ % /usr/libexec/java_home -V
- For this you will see this list of existing version

  Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
  20.0.2 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 20"
  /Users/userName/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-
  20.0.2.1/Contents/Home
  17.0.10 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 17.0.10"
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
  17.0.9 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 17"
  /Users/userName/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-
  17.0.9/Contents/Home
  /Users/userName/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-
  20.0.2.1/Contents/Home
- Then Convert using this command

  ~ % export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-
  17.jdk/Contents/Home
- Check java version

  java --version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).