# Should i upgrade the JAVA version Mac OS X for android development

Tags: java, android, macos

I am getting a prompt to upgrade the java version on my Mac. I am currently on Java 7 , and using android studio tells me java recommended version is 7

If i update the java

1. Does replace the java version?
2. If it does replace ,will android studio still be able to use the new Java JDK , with the only limitation being that it will still be restricted to older java apis

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the update will replace the current installation on your mac. But it's possible to download several version on the JDK and install it in different directory on MacOS.

If you want to use a specific version of JAVA during your development, you can set manually the version of Java used by Android Studio in the property file of Android Studio:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

and set your JAVA version code for the key `JVMOptions/JVMVersion`

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple versions of Java on the same machine. The java version will not be replaced automatically. And yes, android studio will be able to use the new Java JDK, its your choice which version of Java you want to use for your project.

I'm not a mac user, maybe this will help:

[mac os x multiple java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will replace your previous version but only if you click on update.

You can download new version and can install it separately so that you can work on jdk 8 and android studio will work on 7.

Android studio requires jdk 7 right now so leave it with this version only. no need to update to newer version . I myself tried jdk 8 with android studio. It is not compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will replace older java, and since the jdk is new, you have to update you JDK home path (mostly in [.bash_profile](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/) file), So that your android studio will be able to use newer Java version.