# How to install specific Java version using Homebrew?

Tags: java, macos, terminal, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am looking to install Java on Mac using `Homebrew`. This works fine using the command
`brew cask install java`.This installs the latest stable version which is currently - `1.8.0_141`
However how can I install a specific version for example `1.8.0_131`.

Comment: http://effectif.com/mac-os-x/installing-specific-version-of-homebrew-formula  this could help you

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer is there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions

Answer (score 84, accepted):

1. Install homebrew

> /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2. Update homebrew if already installed:

> brew update

3. allow brew to lookup versions

> brew tap homebrew/cask-versions

4. list available java versions

> brew search java

Optional: to find out the minor version of java

> brew info --cask java8

5. install java 8 (or any other version available)

> brew install --cask java8

Comment: it's not the answer for the question, it just install the latest java 8 version

Comment: when you run step 4, you will get a list of available Java versions, step 5 just to demonstrate installing Java version 8

Comment: This seems to be outdated. Do you know how to install java8 with brew now? It intalled java9 and the other command for versions does not show other versions of java

Comment: I just tried again, it's working fine, please follow the steps, you need to run  "brew tap caskroom/versions" first.

Comment: As instructed by homebrew, the command that worked for me was 
`brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8`

First I ran `brew cask uninstall java` to remove the other version I had previously installed.

Comment: Do not forget to update JAVA_HOME: in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file: `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

Comment: I'm receiving `Error: Calling \`brew cask search\` is disabled! Use \`brew search\` instead.` when running `brew cask search java`

Comment: run `brew search java ` then

Comment: Use above instructions plus jEnv (http://www.jenv.be/) to manage multiple versions of JDK/JRE on the same machine and you'll have the ability to switch between java dev environments without a hassle!

Comment: `brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8` and `brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/java8` don't work anymore, see [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/issues/7253) for more details.

Comment: The workaround for now is to `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` and use `brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: I don't understand. The OP is asking how to install a specific version of java8 (131 vs 141). How does that work?

Answer (score 19):

Raising Sean Breckenridge's comment as an answer to increase visibility:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

There is no longer cask named "java8".

Comment: ╰─$ brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
Error: Unknown command: cask

Comment: `brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Answer (score 0):

run `brew update`  command make sure that brew is update to date.

then check brew by following command... to make sure brew works fine

```
brew doctor
```

if its has any issue you have to fix that first ...

Then if you want to install specific version run following command ..

```
brew install java11
```

in my case it's `java11` you can check java available version on java website.

Then go for location

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
```

and make sure jdk file is there...

if there is not any folder just run the following command in terminal...

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
```

change the version after `@11` according to your required jdk version. its gonna tell system about java runtime.

you can check java version by following command.

```
java --version
```