# JDK 9 early access resulted in JRE update on OSX Sierra

Tags: java, macos, java-9

I installed JDK 9 early access (jdk-9 177) on my macbook pro (macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5) using instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions) and [here](http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/install-multiple-jdk-on-mac/).

I was able to install it successfully and then using `jenv`, I set my global java versions as java 8. So when I typed `java -version` from terminal, I could see java 8 on the terminal.

But strangely, the when I opened "System Preferences" -> "Java", the "Java Control Panel" window showed me java 9 version.

Then after some looking around, from other posts, I found out that the "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" was having java 9 JRE for some reason.

I didn't expected it to change my JRE version to 9 when installing JDK 9. I had to uninstall it and reinstall JRE 8 as some of my applications won't work.

Did anyone else face similar issue when installing jdk 9?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that JRE should not be updated?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to install JDK and if I needed JRE for that newly installed JDK version, I know it would be `jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre` folder, I don't want the system JRE to be updated. Or is that how it works?

Comment: I ran into something similar. Consider using Docker or SDKMan. I've been happy with both for JDK 9 on Mac OS.

Comment: @MichaelEaster That's a very good idea, and good use case for me to explore Docker. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I have JDK 9 examples [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/blob/master/README.md) which contains instructions on using Docker with a pre-made image (not by me). There are other techniques but this one is simple.