# Java RE 6 on Mac Os High Sierra

Tags: java, macos

I am using the xlsx package in R Studio which does not seem to work on Java RE 8. I have now been told to use Java RE 6 for R Studio to work, however it seems that for Mac Os High Sierra, the only older version available for download would be Java 7, as Mac OS is no longer included in Java 6 Download Archives.

Is anyone having an idea how I could use Java 6 on Mac Os High Sierra.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

With my latest update of OSX it knocked out my java6 so I had to go dig up this solution again and came across your question.  Not sure whether to put this as an answer or comment, but this solution has worked the best for me:
[Mac OS X and multiple Java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions)

To summarise: (a large part of this is just copy paste from the link above)

1) Install homebrew, jenv, & homebrew-cask

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install jenv
brew tap caskroom/cask
```

2) Add the "caskroom/versions" tap to homebrew using

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
```

3) Install Java6 (or whatever version you want)

```
brew cask install java6
```

4) Add java version to jenv

```
jenv add <javaVersionPathHere>
```

See jenv docs for more info:
http://www.jenv.be/

I especially recommend using the 'jenv local' setup so you can specify java6 for one specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try download it from here https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US