# java 1.8 jar runs in Windows not Ubuntu, "could not find or load main class ..."

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8, jar

I have a jar file that runs fine from the Windows 10 command line, but is not working on my desktop Ubuntu 18.04 command line. The file was exported from Eclipse as a jar, and copied to Ubuntu. The project has about 30 classes over a half dozen packages. I've done some renaming in order to simplify things for this question.

This is the command used to run the jar:

```
java -jar myproject.jar
```

On Ubuntu, I get the error "Could not find or load main class com.a.b.LaunchThis"

Following are some of the things I've tried, based on suggestions from many similar posts. Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a workable answer.

I verified that the current Java is 1.8 using the commands:

```
$ update-alternatives --config java
```

and

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

(I also verified that the program runs using java 8 on Windows.)

I ran the following check, which displays all the files, and confirmed that com/a/b/LaunchThis.class exists and is spelled exactly the same way.

```
java tj myproject.jar
```

The manifest seems correct.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.a.b.LaunchThis
```

I also tried unpacking the jar and running the program directly from the folder /myproject which contains both /com and META-INF. That should work, shouldn't it?

```
java com.a.b.LaunchThis
java com/a/b/LaunchThis
java com.a.b/LaunchThis
```

And from one level outside the myproject folder:

```
java myproject/com/a/b/LaunchThis
java myproject.com.a.b/LaunchThis
java myproject.com.a.b.LaunchThis
java myproject/com.a.b.LaunchThis
```

I am not totally clear on when the syntax requires . or /. The package command in "LaunchThis" which holds the main entry point is the following:

```
package com.a.b;
```

And in each of the above iterations I also tried including "-cp myproject.jar" as an option.

Always the exact same error message.

To be careful about not having a typo in the above, I first ran the ls command to make sure the file could be found (then edited this line to create the variants).

```
ls myproject.com.a.b.LaunchThis.class
```

Any suggestions as to what else to try?

For grins, running with Java11 gets this response:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.a.b.LaunchThis
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/event/EventHandler
```

This makes some sense, because Java11 does not include JavaFX. But Java 8 does include `EventHandler`. It's been a part of Java since JavaFX 2.

UPDATE: I made two "Hello world" jars, one with and one without JavaFX on an Ubuntu installation of Eclipse running OpenJDK 8. To get the version with JavaFX to run, I downloaded the Oracle JDK 1.8, and linked to /lib/etc/jfxrt.jar as an "external jar" library. Both programs run in Eclipse but only the non-FX jar works. The FX jar gives exactly the same error message.

I think this pretty much establishes my problem to be one of not having JavaFX as part of OpenJDK 8.

My plan is to now try out two solutions: (1) copying the Oracle jfxrt.jar into the OpenJDK lib, (2) backloading OpenJFX 8.

Simply installing OpenJFX from repository loads OpenJFX 11, which is a little dated but will work with the OpenJDK 11.

Comment: Does `LaunchThis` have a `public static void main(String[] args)` ?

Comment: Yes. And the exact same jar runs on Windows.

Comment: (1) `java jt jarfile` is an error; did you mean `jar tf jarfile`? (2) _Oracle_ j8 includes JFX, but _OpenJDK_ not necessarily. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166267/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091157/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137891/ (3) But even so it should give a clearer error. Try adding `-verbose` and see if that narrows it down any.

Comment: Fixed the jt/tj mixup. Thanks. I've spent the last couple hours pursuing the JavaFX angle. My discovered my OpenJDK 8 doesn't have jfxrt.jar. So that could well be the problem. Your links look promising. They were not one's I found when searching on JFX missing from OpenJFX 8. OpenJFX default seems to be 11, and doesn't work with OpenJDK8, but one of your links has an earlier version. I did download Oracle 1.8 and was looking at popping it's copy of jfxrt.jar into the OpenJDK8 /lib. Will let you know what ends up working.

Comment: Run it in docker lol

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestion doesn't help in this case. (1) OpenJDK 11 doesn't have JavaFX, turns out to be the main problem. (2) Many users I wish to give a test jar to don't do Docker. (Still learning about Docker myself.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Also wanted to thank you for the -verbose reminder. It didn't help a lot but it's good to have that in one's debugging repertoire, and it did verify all the non-jfx classes loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the repository OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu 18.04 does not include JavaFX. I'm guessing that the error message results from the fact that a JavaFX main() is located on a class that extends the JavaFX class Application.

How to fix this?

There are a number of things I tested.

First, one *could* use Oracle's JDK 1.8 instead. I ruled this out due to licensing issues.

Some sites suggested copying the *jfxrt.jar* from either the Oracle JDK 1.8 or from a working Java program that uses JavaFX and uses a self-contained JRE. I found that if I linked to the Oracle *jfxrt.jar* (located in the `/jre/lib/ext` folder) as an external jar, I could run a simple, "Hello world" javafx program in Eclipse. But I could not run the program after it was exported to a jar.

One answer on a related stackoverflow thread suggested copying over several additional files along with jfxrt.jar, which I tried. This did not work, so I'm not going to pass that on.

The solution that has been most successful came from a link provided in the comment by @dave_thomson_085, [How do I get Java FX running with OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166267/).

This answer involves purging and reinstalling *openjfx* with an older version, and marking it to NOT be subjected to updates.

The code provided by Wolfgang Fahl (which he credits to [Druidefix](https://github.com/JabRef/user-documentation/issues/204)) follows:

```
apt purge openjfx
apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
apt-mark hold openjfx libopenjfx-jni libopenjfx-java
```

Now, I can run and test jars containing Java8 using JavaFX that were built on my Windows Eclipse, on my Ubuntu desktop.

I do get a warning message which I haven't dealt with yet:

```
Gtk-Message: 13:25:40.829: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

But this is not preventing my programs from running.

Comment: I wish we had this link to the related SO question where the exact JavaFX files that should be copied / should exist inside the JDK folders in order to be able to run a JavaFX application on Java 8.
after trial and error what worked for me was to copy jfxrt.jar (from %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext or %JAVA_HOME%\lib\ext) and jfxmedia.dll + jfxwebkit.dll from %JAVA_HOME%\bin