# error: package javafx.application does not exist import javafx.application.Application;

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 OS. I got

```
package javafx.application does not exist
```

error.I read all articles related to topic. I both set my default Java version 8 and also add the openjfx to the Intellij as module and library. Even if I tried solutions I found, still my problem doesn't solved. May it be related to something else that I didn't consider? Which other things I should also check?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you find this file in your JDK? `jdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`
Did you install openjfx? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27178988/2138953

Comment: In path:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
there is no file named jfxrt.jar.
I already installed openjfx (it is in downloads) by looking the answer you shared. And also added the things in it's lib folder to intellij. 
@PAX

Comment: why do you want to use an utterly outdated java/fx version (assuming it's 8 from the folder name)?

Comment: Because prerequisite of the github repo I followed is having Java 8 version, it doesn't work otherwise. @kleopatra

Comment: how unfortunate .. thanks for the info

Comment: _I read all articles related to topic_ a bold statement ;) Maybe you missed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783369/install-openjdkopenjfx-8-on-ubuntu-20 which looks like a straightforward step-by-step instruction

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Java 8, the easiest thing to do (and what I recommend), is to use Oracle JDK 8, not OpenJDK.

Most OpenJDK distributions do not include JavaFX, but Oracle JDK 8 does.

Answer (score -1):

Downloading `jfxrt.jar` file from a github repo, and placing this file inside the necessary path, which is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext` solves the problem :)

(For Ubuntu 20.04, and Java 8)

Comment: I don’t recommend this.  JavaFX requires native code which is not included in `jfxrt.jar`.  While adding `jxfrt.jar` to the path may allow a JavaFX app to compile, it won’t run correctly,  because the required native code is not there.  Even if the native code was separately added,  it would need to be the correct code for the architecture and a binary match the downloaded `jfxrt.jar` native interfaces, which would be unlikely.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).