# How do I uninstall the Java JDK in macOS?

Tags: java, macos

I installed Java version 10, but I can't run React Native with Android because Android doesn't support Java version 10.

Instead, I need to uninstall Java version 10 so that I can install a compatible version instead. How can I do this?

Comment: You might look into this instead for having both versions installed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can get official oracle instruction to remove java from macOS [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml)

In your macOS terminal type this one by one

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

After that you can navigate to specific version of java that you intend to delete by using the following command:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Then type `ls` in your terminal to list down all the Java Virtual Machine Folders.

Finally add the version number you want to delete like this

`sudo rm -rf jdk-10.0.1.jdk`

Instead of **jdk-10.0.1.jdk** you can give any version number which are listed down in your above mentioned folder.

Comment: Ufff! But how friendly things happen on MacOS :)

Comment: @1antares1 Friendly OS = Friendly Things :)

Comment: It was an irony because in Windows, none of this you have to do but it's fine hehe!

Comment: this works for me, really thanks

Answer (score 8):

Update:

1. First remove the java runtime

   ```sh
   $ sudo mv /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin ~/
   $ sudo mv /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane ~/
   ```

   *Now you can close and reopen the System Preferences window to see that the icon is gone.*
2. Next, uninstall the Java JDK. Open a terminal and change to the Java directory:

   ```sh
   $ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
   ```

   You can use `ls` at the prompt to see what is in the directory and copy the jdk's path name with version number that you wish to delete.

   ```sh
   $ ls --directory *jdk*
   examplejdk-7.jdk
   ```

   Copy the exact name of the path you want to remove -- for this example it's `examplejdk-7.jdk`. Next, use that path name **inside of single quotes** (`'examplejdk-7.jdk'`) to move it to your desktop. *Instead of deleting the directory, this moves it to your desktop so you can restore it later in case there's an issue!*

   ```sh
   $ sudo mv 'examplejdk-7.jdk' ~/
   ```
3. To confirm that it has been removed, run this command:

   ```sh
   $ java
   ```

   This should output an error message:

   ```
   No Java runtime present, requesting install
   ```