# How do I install Java on Mac OSX allowing version switching?

Tags: java, macos, java-17

I want to install OpenJDK Java on Mac OSX and have it work alongside other JDK's since it is a newer release.  Currently, I downloaded the tar.gz and placed it in my path but that is hard to maintain.

The only other install I found that do more things automatically is the install via Homebrew cask.  It looks like only the current version too:

```
brew cask info java
```

Shows:

> java: 13,33:5b8a42f3905b406298b72d750b6919f6
>   https://openjdk.java.net/

So I can install it from there, but then what?  Am I stuck only with the new version?

Comment: Just asking, can we keep the question tags restricted to a single version? Since there is no such version-specific installation script/steps anyway. This is a general(non-version specific) question and can suffice to be tagged with only [tag:Java-11], since I assume that is the place where people would start looking out for what the question and answer suggests.

Comment: Scripts in the answers do include specific versions even though it is easy to interpret them for other versions.  But, it is also part of what community members search for, so it is good to help them find the correct answers quickly by helping to bring attention to updated and modern answers and differentiate from old outdated version 6 and version 8 topics.  Having the latest stable version and latest new version I think are reasonable tags to keep.

Comment: I would probably recommend to use [jenv](https://github.com/jenv/jenv) to manage multiple Java versions.

Answer (score 1167, accepted):

**Note:** *These solutions work for various versions of Java including Java 8 through Java 21 (the LTS version).  This includes alternative JDK's from OpenJDK, Oracle, IBM, Azul, Amazon Correto, Graal and more.*

You have a few options for how to do the installation as well as manage JDK switching.  Installation can be done by Homebrew, [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io), [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/), or a manual install.  Switching can be done by [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io), [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/), or manually by setting `JAVA_HOME`.  All of these are described below.

---

## TL;DR - Preferred Methods of Installation

You can install Java using whatever method you prefer including SDKMAN, *asdf*, Homebrew, or a manual install of the tar.gz file.  The advantage of a manual install is that the location of the JDK can be placed in a standardized location for Mac OSX.

However, there are easier options such as *SDKMAN* and *asdf* that also will install other important and common tools for the JVM.  These two primary options are described here.

### Installing and Switching versions with SDKMAN

[**SDKMAN**](https://sdkman.io) is a bit different and handles both the install and the switching.  SDKMAN also places the installed JDK's into its own directory tree, which is typically `~/.sdkman/candidates/java`.  SDKMAN allows setting a global default version, and a version specific to the current shell.

1. Install SDKMAN from https://sdkman.io/install
2. List the Java versions available to make sure you know the version ID

   ```
   sdk list java
   ```
3. Install one of those versions, for example, Java 21 LTS:

   ```
   sdk install java 21-open
   ```

   Or java 19:

   ```
   sdk install java 19.0.2-open
   ```
4. Make Java 17 the default version:

   ```
   sdk default java 17-open
   ```

   Or switch to 17 for the current terminal session:

   ```
   sdk use java 17-open
   ```

When you list available versions for installation using the list command, you will see a wide variety of distributions of Java:

```
sdk list java
```

And install additional versions, such as JDK 11 from Amazon:

```
sdk install java 11.0.14.10.1-amzn
```

SDKMAN can work with previously installed existing versions.  Just do a local install giving your own version label and the location of the JDK:

```
sdk install java my-local-13 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And use it freely:

```
sdk use java my-local-13
```

SDKMAN will automatically manage your `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` for you as you change versions.  And as a note, it installs Java versions to `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/`.

More information is available in the [SDKMAN Usage Guide](https://sdkman.io/usage) along with [other SDK's](https://sdkman.io/sdks) it can install and manage such as Gradle, Maven, Kotlin, Quarkus, Spring Boot, and many others.

---

### Installing and Switching versions with "*asdf*"

[asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) is a version manager that supports installing and managing most languages, frameworks, and developer/devops tools. It has language specific plugins including one [for Java](https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java).

1. First, install *asdf* via https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html (read there to setup your shell correctly), or more simply:

   ```
   brew reinstall asdf
   ```

   and [read the doc](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf) for setting up your shell correctly, but if you are using *asdf* from Homebrew with ZSH you can execute this command to finish setup:

   ```
   echo -e "\n. $(brew --prefix asdf)/libexec/asdf.sh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zshrc
   ```
2. Then install the Java plugin via https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java

   ```
   asdf plugin add java
   ```

   and [read the doc](https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java) for setting up your shell correctly before continuing.  Basically it says to add the following to your `~/.zshrc` file (assuming you are not using another shell):

   ```
   . ~/.asdf/plugins/java/set-java-home.zsh
   ```
3. Now list Java versions:

   ```
   asdf list-all java
   ```
4. Install your favorite flavor and version:

   ```
   asdf install java openjdk-21
   ```

   or install the latest:

   ```
   asdf install java latest
   ```

Other important commands are...

- List your installed versions:

  ```
  asdf list java
  ```
- Set a global Java version:

  ```
  asdf global java openjdk-21
  ```
- Set a local Java version for a directory:

  ```
  asdf local java openjdk-19
  ```

It's that easy!  *asdf* will automatically manage your PATH and JAVA_HOME for you as you change versions.  As a note, *asdf* installs Java versions to `~/.asdf/installs/java`.

There are other languages and plugins for *asdf* here from the repository page: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-plugins

---

## Other Methods of Installation

### Install with Homebrew

The version of Java available in Homebrew Cask previous to October 3, 2018 was indeed the Oracle JVM.  Now, however, it has now been updated to OpenJDK.  Be sure to update Homebrew and then you will see the lastest version available for install.

1. [install Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if you haven't already.  Make sure it is updated:

   ```
    brew update
   ```
2. Add the casks tap:

   ```
    brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
   ```

   These casks change their Java versions often, and there might be other taps out there with additional Java versions.
3. Look for installable versions:

   ```
    brew search java
   ```

   or for Eclipse Temurin versions:

   ```
    brew search temurin
   ```
4. Check the details on the version that will be installed:

   ```
    brew info java
   ```

   or for the Temurin version:

   ```
    brew info temurin
   ```
5. Install a specific version of the JDK such as `java11`, `temurin8`, `temurin11`, `temurin17`, or just `java` or `temurin` for the most current of that distribution.  For example:

   ```
    brew install java

    brew install --cask temurin
   ```

And these will be installed into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` which is the traditional location expected on Mac OSX.  There might be additional steps to make the JDK active reported at the end of the install process.

### Install manually from OpenJDK download page:

If you need any and every version of Java, this is a good place to look.

1. Download OpenJDK for Mac OSX from http://jdk.java.net/ (for example [Java 17](https://jdk.java.net/17/) and [Java 21](https://jdk.java.net/21/))
2. Unarchive the OpenJDK tar, and place the resulting folder (i.e. `jdk-19.jdk`) into your `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` folder since this is the standard and expected location of JDK installs.  You can also install anywhere you want in reality.
3. Set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point at direction where you unarchived the JDK.

For further information see the answer [specific to manual installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53273225/3679676).  Also see the section below "Switching versions manually" for more information on how to manage multiple manual installations.

### Other installation options:

Some other flavours of OpenJDK are:

**[Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/) Java Zulu** certified builds of OpenJDK can be installed by following the [instructions on their site](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/).

> Zulu® is a certified build of OpenJDK that is fully compliant with the Java SE standard. Zulu is 100% open source and freely downloadable. Now Java developers, system administrators, and end-users can enjoy the full benefits of open source Java with deployment flexibility and control over upgrade timing.

[**Amazon Correto**](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) OpenJDK builds have an easy to use an installation package for Java 8, 11, 17, and Java 21.  It installs to the standard `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` directory on Mac OSX.

> Amazon Corretto is a no-cost, multiplatform, production-ready distribution of the Open Java Development Kit (OpenJDK). Corretto comes with long-term support that will include performance enhancements and security fixes. Amazon runs Corretto internally on thousands of production services and Corretto is certified as compatible with the Java SE standard. With Corretto, you can develop and run Java applications on popular operating systems, including Linux, Windows, and macOS.

[**Microsoft Java JDK**](https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk) - certified builds of OpenJDK from Microsoft.

---

## Where is my JDK?!?!

To find locations of previously installed Java JDK's installed at the default system locations, use:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

> Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
> 19 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 19" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/19/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
> 18.0.1.1 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 18.0.1.1" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
> 17 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 17" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
> 11, x86_64:    "Java SE 11"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
> 1.8.301.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

You can also report just the location of a specific Java version using `-v`.  For example for Java 17:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17
```

> /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

Knowing the location of the installed JDK's is also useful when using tools like JEnv, or adding a local install manually to SDKMAN -- and you need to know where to find them.

If you need to find JDK's installed by other tools, check these locations:

- SDKMAN installs to `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/`
- *asdf* install to `~/.asdf/installs/java`

---

## Version Switching

If you are using *SDKMAN* or *asdf* you are already covered and can stop reading!  Otherwise, here are some options to switch existing VM installations.

### Switching versions manually

The Java executable is a wrapper that will use whatever JDK is configured in `JAVA_HOME`, so you can change that to also change which JDK is in use.

For example, if you installed or untar'd JDK 16 to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk` if it is the highest version number it should already be the default, if not you could simply set:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And now whatever Java executable is in the path will see this and use the correct JDK.

A [simple way to change JDKs](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk#switch-between-different-jdk-versions) is to create a function in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file:

```
jdk() {
    version=$1
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v"$version");
    java -version
}
```

And then change JDKs simply by:

```
jdk 1.8
jdk 9
jdk 11
jdk 13
```

---

Edits:

- removed Jabba and JENV as both appear to have stagnated, issue count is climbing dramatically, and issues/PR's are not being addressed by the maintainers.

Comment: For manual install I think you need to set `JAVA_HOME` in order to select a specific version, something like `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version>)` in your `.bash_profile`

Comment: @PeterHull some of the Java version managers do not like having `JAVA_HOME` set manually and they manage it themselves.  JEnv for sure will not adjust it if previously set, not sure about Jabba and SDKMAN but they normally will manage that setting.  Only a manual install with NO version switching should ever set this value directly.

Comment: quite agree, it would be good if you could note that in your answer as the original question asked for version switching and setting JAVA_HOME is the (only?) way to do it for the manual install method.

Comment: I'm worried about adding it @PeterHull because if people set it then do the other methods, some fail to work once `JAVA_HOME` is manually set.  I added notes about it and your comment is right there, I'll think on it.

Comment: Java in brew cask changed to OpenJDK 11 yesterday, Oct 3, 2018.

Comment: Possibly the most extensive and useful answer to running different JDKs on MacOS covering many different approaches, some I'd never come across before.

Comment: Your Homebrew instruction for Java11 now seems obsolete:  `brew cask install java11`
“Error: Cask 'java11' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.”

Comment: @FlashSheridan repeat step #2 above if you haven't lately, then you should see the alternative Java versions again

Comment: I updated the steps in the answer to note that you might need to run step #2 again if you are out of date, or use the fully qualified version in a later step (example provided).

Comment: The introduction sentence mentions the availability of early access builds but does not explain how to get them. Care to elaborte?

Comment: Can't install java8 using cask now, only java11 and java6 are available: Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

Comment: @VitaliiDmitriev the casks change over time.  You can install adoptopenjdk versions by tapping `brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk` and then `brew search jdk` to see the versions.  There are other taps out there maybe, but hombrew removed some Java versions from their default casks.

Comment: I have added a bit more information for the homebrew install including adding the tap for AdoptOpenJDK

Comment: For those thinking about using `sdkman` to install JDKs + `jenv` to switch among them: you'll need to know that the JAVA_HOME equivalent for sdkman installations is ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/<identifier> . But anyway if you can stay with brew instead of sdkman, it's easier.

Comment: @hmijail if using sdkman why use jenv at all, sdkman can already switch the JDK.

Comment: @JaysonMinard if you only need to switch the global JDK, then sdkman is enough. But jenv allows more flexibility, like setting a shell-specific or directory-specific JDK, which for me is necessary.

Comment: Is it possible to set a certain java version for certain programs on a mac a bit like in this discussion? https://community.ui.com/questions/Running-Unifi-Controller-on-Java-9-10-and-11/f1ac1330-40b8-4af6-83b6-8d55e48e4a32

Comment: The problem with the sdkman installation is that sdkman uses a different directory and no Info.plist for the JVM, so `/usr/libexec/java_home` isn't aware of them.

Comment: Please improve the 'Install manually from OpenJDK download page' section and provide more detail including how to set up environment variables etc, so that MacOS does not point to the default Java installation that came with that OS version.

Comment: @AndrewS you are allowed to suggest edits directly.

Comment: @Jason, I came here because I did not know and felt this was a weakness in the document you could improve.

Comment: I used SDKMAN and found it useful that it could install and manage already installed Java versions.

Comment: I was using SDKMAN which worked fine most of the time but recently hit a problem with building Kotlin Multiplatform directly in XCode. While it was working from android studio the  build phase script in XCode recognised only java installed in the system listed under `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`. I followed JEnv installation and with this one it works.

Answer (score 39):

This is how I did it.

**Step 1:**  Install Java 11

You can download Java 11 dmg for mac from here: [https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html)

**Step 2:** After installation of Java 11. Confirm installation of all versions. Type the following command in your terminal.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

**Step 3:** Edit .bash_profile

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

**Step 4:** Add 11.0.1 as default. (Add below line to bash_profile file).

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.1)
```

to switch to any version

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v X.X.X)
```

Now Press CTRL+X to exit the bash. Press 'Y' to save changes.

**Step 5:** Reload bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Step 6:** Confirm current version of Java

```
java -version
```

Comment: Nice solution. But what if still have java -version pointed to 8 while I have exported JAVA_HOME 11?

Comment: The question is asking about Open JDK, but you linked to the Oracle JDK instead. The Open JDK doesn't appear to have an installer or installation instructions.

Comment: In response to @AlexGera - add this line:
    export $PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: I still had to execute this command after adding @FuadEfendi 's line.
% export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17.0.1`. Make sure you add ` symbol at the end of the version number. It takes as the code formatter here.

Answer (score 16):

With Homebrew and jenv:

Assumption: Mac machine and you already have installed homebrew.

Install Java from official Oracle website. You can install multiple versions of JDK. It will install on the following path:

```
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.11.0_2.jdk/
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/
```

Without `jenv`, system will use the java which installed last.

If you want to use/manage multiple version then you can use `jenv`:

Install and configure jenv:

```
$ brew install jenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Add the installed java to jenv:

```
$ jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
$ jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

To see all the installed java:

```
$ jenv versions
```

Above command will give the list of installed java:

```
  system
  1.8
* 1.8.0.291 (set by /Users/lpatel/.jenv/version)
  14
  14.0
  14.0.2
  oracle64-1.8.0.291
  oracle64-14.0.2
```

Configure the java version which you want to use:

```
$ jenv global 1.8.0.291
```

Comment: `Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask-cask instead`, then `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-cask/' not found`

Comment: what @ChumiestBucket said -this solution has multiple problems

Comment: @ChumiestBucket I have updated the solution, let me know if you face any problem in this one. Thanks !

Comment: @WestCostProjects  FYI

Answer (score 13):

**Manually switching system-default version without 3rd party tools:**

As detailed in [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169445/6730571), on macOS `/usr/bin/java` is a wrapper tool that will use Java version pointed by `JAVA_HOME` or if that variable is not set will look for Java installations under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` and will use the one with highest version. It determines versions by looking at `Contents/Info.plist` under each package.

Armed with this knowledge you can:

- control which version the system will use by renaming `Info.plist` in versions you don't want to use as default (that file is not used by the actual Java runtime itself).
- control which version to use for specific tasks by setting `$JAVA_HOME`

I've just verified this is still true with OpenJDK & Mojave.

On a brand new system, there is no Java version installed:

```
$ java -version
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

Cancel this, download OpenJDK 11 & 12ea on https://jdk.java.net ;
install OpenJDK11:

```
$ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
$ sudo tar xzf ~/Downloads/openjdk-11.0.1_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

System java is now 11:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
[...]
```

Install OpenJDK12 (early access at the moment):

```
$ sudo tar xzf ~/Downloads/openjdk-12-ea+17_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

System java is now 12:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "12-ea" 2019-03-19
[...]
```

Now let's "hide" OpenJDK 12 from system java wrapper:

```
$ cd jdk-12.jdk/Contents/
$ sudo mv Info.plist Info.plist.disabled
```

System java is back to 11:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
[...]
```

And you can still use version 12 punctually by manually setting `JAVA_HOME`:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home
$ java -version
openjdk version "12-ea" 2019-03-19
[...]
```

Comment: and it should also be true now with [AdoptOpenJDK builds](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2018/10/macos-binary-changes)

Answer (score 10):

If you have multiple versions installed on your machine, add the following in bash profile:

> export JAVA_HOME_7=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.7)
>
> export JAVA_HOME_8=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
>
> export JAVA_HOME_9=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v9)

And add the following aliases:

> alias java7='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_7'
>
> alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_8'
>
> alias java9='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_9'

And can switch to required version by using the alias:

In terminal:

`~ >> java7
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_7_HOME`

Comment: yep, this was covered in another answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is using [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/)! See https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2018/09/26/switching-between-jdk-8-and-11-using-sdkman/

First install SDKMAN:  https://sdkman.io/install and then...

1. Install Oracle JDK 8 with: `sdk install java 8.0.181-oracle`
2. Install OpenJDK 11 with: `sdk install java 11.0.0-open`

To switch:

- Switch to JDK 8 with `sdk use java 8.0.181-oracle`
- Switch to JDK 11 with `sdk use java 11.0.0-open`

To set a default:

- Default to JDK 8 with `sdk default java 8.0.181-oracle`
- Default to JDK 11 with `sdk default java 11.0.0-open`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/#/) to install and switch between multiple java versions. It has plugins for other languages as well. You can install asdf with Homebrew

```
brew install asdf
```

When asdf is configured, install java plugin

```
asdf plugin-add java
```

Pick a version to install

```
asdf list-all java
```

For example to install and configure adoptopenjdk8

```
asdf install java adoptopenjdk-8.0.272+10
asdf global java adoptopenjdk-8.0.272+10
```

And finally if needed, configure JAVA_HOME for your shell. Just add to your shell init script such as ~/.zshrc in case of zsh:

```
. ~/.asdf/plugins/java/set-java-home.zsh
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, There is no need to install all the additional applications/packages.

Check available versions using the command:

```
> /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (8):
    11, x86_64: "Java SE 11-ea" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
    10.0.2, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    9.0.1, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_181-zulu-8.31.0.1, x86_64:    "Zulu 8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_151, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_80, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Now if you want to pick Azul JDK 8 in the above list, and NOT Oracle's Java SE 8, invoke the command as below:

```
> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_181
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

To pick Oracle's Java SE 8 you would invoke the command:

```
> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_151
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
```

As you can see the version number provided shall be the unique set of strings: 1.8.0_181 vs 1.8.0_151

Comment: Shouldn't the first example have a version string `1.8.0_181-zulu-8.31.0.1` ?  or is it partial matching?

Comment: This doesn't actually change anything to use the version of Java, it just reports the location of the `JAVA_HOME`.  Manual switching using these commands is covered in my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer extends on Jayson's excellent answer with some more opinionated guidance on the best approach for your use case:

- SDKMAN is the best solution for most users.  It's easy to use, doesn't have any weird configuration, and makes managing multiple versions for [lots of other Java ecosystem](https://sdkman.io/sdks) projects easy as well.
- Downloading Java versions via Homebrew and switching versions via jenv is a good option, but requires more work.  For example, [the Homebrew commands in this highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195815/1125159) don't work anymore.  jenv is slightly harder to setup, the [plugins](https://github.com/jenv/jenv/tree/master/available-plugins) aren't well documented, and the README says the project is looking for a new maintainer.  jenv is still a great project, solves the job, and the community should be thankful for the wonderful contribution.  SDKMAN is just the better option cause it's so great.
- Jabba is written is a multi-platform solution that provides the same interface on Mac, Windows, and PC (it's written in Go and that's what allows it to be multiplatform).  If you care about a multiplatform solution, this is a huge selling point.  If you only care about running multiple versions on your Mac, then you don't need a multiplatform solution.  SDKMAN's support for tens of popular SDKs is what you're missing out on if you go with Jabba.

Managing versions manually is probably the worst option.  If you decide to manually switch versions, you can use this Bash code instead of Jayson's verbose code (code snippet from the [homebrew-openjdk README](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk#switch-between-different-jdk-versions):

```
jdk() {
        version=$1
        export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v"$version");
        java -version
 }
```

Jayson's answer provides the basic commands for SDKMAN and jenv.  Here's more info on [SDKMAN](https://mungingdata.com/java/sdkman-multiple-versions-java-sbt-scala/) and more info on [jenv](https://mungingdata.com/java/jenv-multiple-versions-java/) if you'd like more background on these tools.

Comment: thanks I made updates to the original answer for the simpler shell switching.

Answer (score 0):

To stay with a specific major release, activate the AdoptOpenJDK tap with brew tap and then install the desired version with brew cask install:

```
$ brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
$ brew cask install <version>
```

To install AdoptOpenJDK 14 with HotSpot, run:

```
$ brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
$ brew cask install adoptopenjdk14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the JDK version in any way you want.

- Homebrew
- SDK man
- Manually

Then, I recommend using JENV to switch between different versions and use the JDK you need globally or locally.

You can find more details about how to install and use JENV here ->
https://blog.adamgamboa.dev/2021/06/17/using-jenv-to-switch-jkd-versions/