# java version update to 11 still shows 8

Tags: java, macos, java-11

I am using macOS Monterey (v 12.0.1). Below is my Java version :

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

First of all I do not understand `"1.8.0_281"`, does it mean it is `java 8`?

I want to update the Java version to 11. So, I have downloaded and installed `jdk-11.0.13_osx-x64_bin.dmg`, it shows successfully installed. But now when I check `java -version` still it shows `java version "1.8.0_281"`. How can I update my java version to java 11 ?

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) You need change what `java` is resolving to; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657630/139985

Comment: Did you read it? You can find the answer below the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524112/how-do-i-install-java-on-mac-osx-allowing-version-switching[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524112/how-do-i-install-java-on-mac-osx-allowing-version-switching)

Comment: @AnarXocayev - The link in your comment is broken ...

Comment: @StephenC, yours is perfect answer that link has solved my problem.

Answer (score 11):

1. List all Java versions installed on your Mac.

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    11.0.11 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.241.07 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_241 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home
```

2. Set Desired version to JAVA_HOME environment variable.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.11`
```

3. Update the .bashrc or .zshrc file in your ~ Home directory.

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Add/Edit this line in the file and Save.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.11)
```

4. Open a New window in Terminal and verify if it worked.

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194, mixed mode)
```

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` does not list JDK 11 installed via homebrew