# Choosing Java version when Installing OpenCV with Homebrew

Tags: java, opencv, cmake, homebrew

I am trying to install OpenCV using the Homebrew-based installation instructions from the [documentation](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#install-opencv-3-x-under-macos).

```
brew edit opencv # edit file and set -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON 
brew install --build-from-source opencv
```

Then I try to use the resulting OpenCV jar in my Java project but it fails at runtime because the Java version used to compile does not match my runtime.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/opencv/core/Core has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I need it to be compiled with Java 8 but it is being compiled with Java 10.

**How can I tell Homebrew/OpenCV which version of javac to use?**

I have tried setting my JAVA_HOME to the desired location and it still does not work.

Comment: Where are you setting JAVA_HOME, and are you running `java -version` before building OpenCV?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions

Comment: I've tried setting JAVA_HOME in my `~/.bash_profile` and adding it to my `PATH`. I have also tried using `jenv` and setting the global java version. Yes, before building OpenCV (using command above) I've run `java -version` and it returns: `java version "1.8.0_192"`

Comment: I am having similar issue. Anybody managed to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

See [Set target java version when build OpenCV with brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115757/set-target-java-version-when-build-opencv-with-brew)

Where user minhtus answers his own question;

> Found the answer, put the extra -DOPENCV_JAVA_TARGET_VERSION=1.8 args
> to cmake in brew formula.

You can do this using the command;

> brew edit opencv

And then in the editor, look for;

> ```
> args = std_cmake_args + %W[
>   -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=
>   -DBUILD_JASPER=OFF
>   -DBUILD_JPEG=OFF
>   -DBUILD_OPENEXR=OFF
>   -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF
> ```

And insert the the java version flag.