# Set target java version when build OpenCV with brew

Tags: java, opencv, ant, homebrew

I'm using brew to build OpenCV with java support following [this tutorial](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#install-opencv-3-x-under-macos). After built successful I got the error `class file has wrong version 57.0, should be 52.0` when using. I'm using OpenJDK 8, how can I target the build to this version. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the [answer](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/13435), put the extra `-DOPENCV_JAVA_TARGET_VERSION=1.8` args to cmake in brew formula.