# How to Install multiple JDK minor versions using Brew in Mac OS (not major versions)

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I already have installed JDK 1.8.0_192 using homebrew,

```
brew cask install java8
```

For development purposes, I want to also install JDK 1.8.0_152. Is there a way to accomplish this using homebrew?

**Note**: This is not about installing multiple **major** versions (i.e. v1.7, v1.8) which is answered in [Mac OS X and multiple Java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions). 
This question is about installing **minor** versions (i.e. v1.8.0_152, v1.8.0_192).