# Want to Update Java 1.6 to 1.8 in MAC

Tags: java

Please help me I want to update my java version 1.6 to 1.8 in mac using Terminal, if anyone knows please share details.

Thank You

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions

Answer (score 1):

use `sdkman` to manage multiple java sdks

https://sdkman.io/

https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli

https://medium.com/@ajeesh2705/use-multiple-version-of-java-6219258bd8eb

Answer (score 1):

Install `homebrew` if you don't have it:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install `java 1.8`:

```
brew cask install java8
# or   brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
#      brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

Delete the java 1.6 later if you wish.