# Remove java installed by homebrew on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, homebrew

I had installed homebrew for some tool which was working best when installed with homebrew, so I think from one of the dependencies it installed Java 20 as well so whenever I run `java --version` or `javac --version` it gives

```
openjdk 20 2023-03-21
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 20)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 20, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When running `which java` gives following:

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/java
```

But when I run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` I get:

```
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

So my question is, how can I disable or remove java from homebrew so that I can use the java8 which is required for my project?

Comment: I thought homebrew was a Mac thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the java using below-mentioned command:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies java
```

To ensure that you are using java 8, you need to add path into bash file(~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc)

Command to set path:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto/bin:$PATH
```

After that do:

```
source (~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc)
```

check the java version again. Hope, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Maninder gave you the answer you were looking for.

Later, If you want to use multiple versions of Java, How about using 'jEenv'? (You may have already tried this method.)

"jEnv is a command line tool to help you forget how to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable".
This is a greate answer to installing/using jEnv.

[Mac OS X and multiple Java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I dont need multiple Java versions but will keep that in mind!